# How to manually restore emails in Lion?

Tags: macos, mail.app, backup, upgrade, plist

Before upgrading to Mac OS X Lion with a clean install, I backed up Mail app according to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2340655?start=0&tstart=0) article on Apple Discussions. I know have the `com.apple.mail` file and the `Mail` directory and I have no idea how to restore it. As it seems, theses paths have changed. Do you have any ideas on how to restore my emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the contents of the mail directory in /Users/yourusername/Library/Mail (or  ~/Library/Mail in other words)

com.apple.mail.plist goes to /Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences (~/Library/Preferences)

Comment: I've done that already. It didn't work and that's why I'm asking it here. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @João I have confirmed this process works with a clean install of Lion. If it didn't work for you, you may be experiencing a different problem. Are there any more details you can provide?

Comment: No, @Adam. But hey, I completely forgot I had all my emails stored on my server, so no big deal. I tried doing it a few more times, but it didn't work for me. I'm not using a DP version of Lion, I'm using the one from App Store (I know it may not make the difference, but it's the only extra detail I've got).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly copy the com.apple.mail.plist from the backup to the user library (~/Library/preferences) and it does ask to replace, just click yes. 
[image: com.apple.mail.plist]

Secondly copy the mail folder to the user library (~/Library) and when complete, just open mail as normal.

[image]

Comment: I've done that already. It didn't work and that's why I'm asking it here. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @João Ramos You are completely spot on. Copying the mail.plist and even any other preference file related to mail does not work any longer in Lion. It is a real pain in the neck. This worked for as long as OS X existed, on top of that they killed off mobile me. I did not realize that it was killing off also the synchronization of the mail accounts. Yes it was clearly stated by Apple, however somehow I was thinking about iPhone and iPad which can be synchronized. The only other option seem to use migration assistant, but that makes not much sense as it is an all or nothing approach. That leaves